# Using CGI to trigger applications

Tags: python, opengl, cgi

Is it possible for CGI to be used to trigger an application with a windowing.

Here is my workflow for details:
I am sending a post request to a script in my cgi-bin folder. It is successfully responding to all my post requests and data is being successfully returned. Now this is what I am doing in a part of that script.

```
subprocess.call("python app.py", shell=True)
print 'Done'
```

When I locally use my python script, this works well (it is supposed to output a video). I am using `openGL` to render this video and my current limitation is that for the video rendering to happen, the window must be created (I have done that using `Qt framework for python`).

I have set `chmod 777` permissions to the cgi-bin directory, so that there are no write restrictions. I believe the issue is that it has not been possible to create the window using CGI call.

Is there any way possible to do that? Or any other alternative way to render this video?

Comment: What is the returncode of `subprocess.call`?

Comment: Generally you need the environment variable: `$DISPLAY` to point to your X server (probably `DISPLAY=:0.0`) for this to work. Fortunately environment variables are very easy to set when working with CGI. The bigger issue, however, is that the user that runs your http daemon (or the user who owns the cgi program) is probably the user that will try to connect to the X server. You may need to add them to the authorized list of users for whatever user runs the X server. I am assuming this is Linux/BSD. If it is running on OS X, then it is quite a different story.

Comment: @ekhumoro the return code is 1.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman currently my $DISPLAY env variable is set :0, can you exactly tell me the specific settings to make (I am still on localhost on Ubuntu 13.10 before I push to the server which is also Ubuntu 13.10)